# MySQL - Does a Nested Stored Procedure use the calling Definer as Invoker?

Tags: mysql, security

When Stored Procedure A (SPA) uses DEFINER security, but calls Stored Procedure B (SPB) that uses INVOKER security, does Stored Procedure B check the INVOKER access against the DEFINER access of the calling SP, or the original INVOKER/CURRENT_USER()?

Answer (score 0):

It appears MySQL does use the originating security caller as the Invoker of a nested call. I executed a few tests to check the above, and when SPA uses a DEFINED account with proper privileges, it uses those account credentials as the INVOKER in SPB (which executes fine), but when I call SPB with an account that only has (for example) EXECUTE privilege but not SELECT (and SPB performs a SELECT) it fails.

As such, a SP with DEFINER security passed that DEFINER account as INVOKER to any nested SP.